# Number of points reduced in projection

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Several points in space are projected orthogonally on some three planes $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Could it happen that in the three projections, plane $\alpha$ contains 3 points, plane $\beta$ contains 7 points, and plane $\gamma$ contains 10 points?

Comment: This needs a better title~!

Comment: How about "reconstructing a set from three projections"?

Comment: @Maesumi I changed the title, please edit it, your suggestion is better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, consider
$$(1,1,0), (1,2,0), (1,3,0), (1,4,0), (1,5,0), (1,6,0), (1,7,0), (2,1,0), (3,1,0), (2,2,0)$$
and projections to the standard coordinate planes.

Comment: Geometrically, how would I interpret this rather than just giving points that work?

Comment: Coincident or repeated points in projection ?